# How do I jump to a non-alphabetical mark in vim?

Tags: vim, markers

when in normal mode, I can type `m4` to mark a line.

- Plugins that show the marks in the gutter will print this mark as a `$` (it seems).
- a list of `:marks` does not list this non-alphabetical mark

but typing any of `m0` though `m9` jumps to files last closed, [per the vim docs](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/vim-3.0.refcard.html#7Mar).

Are non-alphabetical marks a bug?
Can I jump to them, and how?

Answer (score 4):

If you read `:h m` you should see it's specified to work with `m{a-zA-Z}`. The `m` operator is used to define marks, however if you want to go to a mark location you should use `'{a-zA-Z0-9}`, so in order to jump to a numbered mark you should use that instead.

With regards to being able to define numbered marks manually, that can't be done, `{0-9}` are special marks that are set from the `.viminfo` file. Quoting from the docs :

> Numbered marks '0 to '9 are quite different.  They can not be set
>   directly. They are only present when using a viminfo file
>   |viminfo-file|.  Basically '0 is the location of the cursor when you
>   last exited Vim, '1 the last but one time, etc.  Use the "r" flag in
>   'viminfo' to specify files for which no Numbered mark should be
>   stored.  See |viminfo-file-marks|.

Comment: You say that numbered marks cannot be manually defined, but in Vim 7.4 that works for me — and so I cannot comment on the docs info you've quoted.  I'll upvote because you provide interesting info.